# Firebase Insert New Child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem when inserting new child. I assign a button to add new subchild into the same child.

But this creates a new subchild in different child.

This is my code

```
 private void status(){
    dbStatus = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("LIST OF FORM");
    String status = "Approve";
    ApprovedStatus app = new ApprovedStatus(status);

    dbStatus.push().setValue(app);
    dbStatus.push().orderByChild("email").equalTo(tvEmail.getText().toString());
}
```

Database structure
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do a two-step process:

1. Execute a query to find the nodes with the specific email address.
2. Loop over the results and update each of them.

Something like this:

```
dbStatus = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("LIST OF FORM");

Query query = dbStatus.orderByChild("email").equalTo(tvEmail.getText().toString());

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            userSnapshot.getRef().child("status").setValue("Approve");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of warnings to the OP, make sure to handle the cases where no matching form or more than one form is found for the given email and make sure to add failure listeners to the `setValue` call to make sure the data is actually committed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

`dbStatus = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("LIST OF FORM").child("youchildnamehere");`

if you have multiple child's use iteration and add status

Comment: i can't. I wanted it to find using orderbychild that match with the email and then add status under the same child.